# Swift 5 Firebase Query by child/key

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

In my database, all posted images have an ever increasing number associated as key to them.

So the first image has the key "1", the second "2" , the 1000th image has the key "1000"

Now I want to query them ordered by ascending order including pagination. So starting with the newest 10, then continue with 11-20 and so on.

How can I Achieve that without using a child to query? currently I need to give it a child (e.g "id" and then the key) in order to be able to query it. As the database is quickly growing, this will lead to unnecessary saved data.

example

```
"root" {
  "images" {
         "1" {
           "id" : 1
             }
         "2" {
           "id" : 2
        }
```

etc.

i want to remove the "id" part and still be able to query it + pagination

currently I am only able to query it properly when I include the child part.

Answer (score 0):

Keys in the Firebase Realtime Database are always going to be strings. So even if you put a numeric value in them, the database will treat them as strings. This is especially important when it comes to ordering, because strings are ordered lexicographically.

In lexicographic this is the correct order of some relevant keys:

```
1
10
11
19
2
20
21
29
3
30
```

But it is very unlikely that you want them in this order, you want key 10 to be (well) after key 2.

To fix this, you should store the keys with a fixed length:

```
001
010
011
019
002
020
021
029
003
030
```

I used a `"0"` for padding here, but using a space would also work.

Once you have the keys padded like this, you can get a slice of the keys with:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: "001").queryEnding(atValue: "010")
```

---

Note that using sequential numeric keys is an antipattern in Firebase. I recommend reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) to learn more on that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This issue I see is that I don't know how many images will be posted. So I guess I have to stay on the way I used to do it. It can be 10k, 100k, 1 mil.

Comment: That's one of the many reasons for not using sequential numeric indexes as keys. But if you choose to keep those, you will have to pick a maximum number of them in order to be able to query the keys, as I explained in my answer.